# Spring mvc - one page with multiple forms

Tags: forms, spring, view

I'm new to Spring and I'm facing one problem pretty long time. I try to google around but I didn't find any easy to understand manual how to solve it.
My problem is that, I need a page, let's call it home page, on which there are going to be several forms.
Then I need to proceed each form to specific controller and from controller return again home view. I am solving this by using SimpleUrlHandlerMapping. For example when I wanned to have loginForm on home page I did it this way:
- create view loginForm.jsp

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

    <fieldset>  
       <legend>Login</legend>
          <form:form method="post" action="loginForm.htm">
                 Mail:<form:input path="mail"/> </br>
                 Password:<form:password path="password" /> </br>
                 <input type="Submit" value="Logni!" /> 
          </form:form>
      </fieldset>
```

- create controller for loginForm.jsp ... just classic SimpleFormController returning home success view
- mapping

  ```
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
      <property name="mappings">
          <props>
              <prop key="/home.htm">homeCtrl</prop>
              <prop key="/loginForm.htm">loginFormCtrl</prop>
              <prop key="/loginSuccess.htm">loginSuccessCtrl</prop>
              <prop key="/registerForm.htm">registerFormCtrl</prop>
              <prop key="/registerSuccess.htm">registerSuccessCtrl</prop>
          </props>
       </property>
  </bean>


   <bean id="loginFormCtrl" class="web.LoginFormController" >
       <property name="sessionForm" value="false"/>
      <property name="commandClass" value="user.User"/>
      <property name="formView" value ="loginForm" />  
      <property name="validator" ref="loginValidator"/>      
      <property name="successView" value="loginSuccess.htm" />
      <property name="user" ref ="user" />
      <property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="loginSuccessCtrl" class="web.LoginSuccessController"/>
  ```
- include form page in home page
  my home.jsp looks something like this

  ```
  <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include.jsp" %>
  <h1>Translator</h1>
  <h3> Welcome user <c:out value="${model.mail}"/> it's <c:out value="${model.time}"     /></h3>
  <jsp:include page="/loginForm.htm" />
  <jsp:include page="/registerForm.htm" />
  ```

The problem I'm facing to is whenever an error in validator occurs(eg. invalid password or username) it redirects my page to formView value - loginForm, when I try setting formView to  home value then it false in some strange long error message. So when an error in validator occurs I'd like to keep user on home page and show message from validator there and not to redirect to loginForm.htm . I think it can't be done the way I'm doing it so far, so can you give me please any easy and clear to understand tutorial for multiple forms on one page problem solving? I'd preffer non annotation way, because I'm not clear about annotations yet.
Thanks for advises.